# Is the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_f) $ separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the metric space$(\mathbb{R}^\omega,d_f) $

Where, $\mathbb{R}^\omega =\{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset {\mathbb{R}}\} $ and $\forall x, y\in\mathbb{R}^\omega$

$$d_f(x, y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{}{\frac{2^{-i}|x_i -y_i|}{1+|x_i -y_i|}}$$

> Question : Is the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_f) $ separable?

$(\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_f) $ is separable if it has a countable dense subset.

Comment: Product of at most continuum many separable spaces is separable. Here we have a countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ (uncountable wouldn't be a metric space).

Comment: Sir, is this metric $d_f$ on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ topologically equivalent to the euclidean product metric on the product space $\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}×... (\omega \space times) $?

Comment: Yes, $d(x, y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is just one of many ways to make a metric (here $|x-y|$) bounded, and if we have metric spaces $X_1, X_2, ...$ with uniformly bounded metrics $d_1, d_2, ...$ (say, $d_i\leq 1$), then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}d_k(x_i, y_i)$ defines a metric on the product $X_1\times X_2\times ...$, and the topology is that of Tychonoff product topology.

Comment: Sir, is this topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega }$ box topology? If this metric generates the box topology, then $\mathbb{R}^{\omega }$  in this box topology will not be separable. Correct me sir if I make any mistake.

Comment: If you are using the terminology from Munkres's book, then $(\mathbb{R}^{\omega},d_{f})$ has the same topology as the product topology --- not the box topology.

Comment: Ok sir. It's a countable product. And this is product topology. Thank you sir. It really helpful for me. Sir, can you give me any reference for the proof?

Comment: For the proof, look up that countable product of metrizable spaces is metrizable. It should be contained there.

Comment: Ok air thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$, $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty 1/2^i< \varepsilon/2$. Then choose
$r_1,\dots, r_N \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{2^{-i}|x_i-r_i|}{1+|x_i-r_i|} < \varepsilon/2$. Set $r=(r_1,\dots,r_N,0,0,0,\dots)$. Now $d_f(x,r)< \varepsilon$. This shows that the set of rational sequences which are eventually $0$ is dense. This set is countable.

Comment: Sir, instead of $2^{i}$ , there should be $2^{-i}$ . There is a typo. But well explained. Thank you sir.

Comment: Of course! It's corrected.